# Academic writing-questions on the topic, "Capitalisation"

Tags: capitalization

Should names of languages within sentences be capitalised? Example french, spanish,russian.

Comment: Yes, in English names of languages are proper nouns, like names of countries.

Comment: Personally, although I'd normally capitalise all noun usages referring to a  language, and all "adjectival" usages where the intended sense *currently* still means *using or from the specified language or country*, I don't capitalise *a french kiss, a bottle of scotch, a china cup*. But whereas nearly everyone does the same as me with the last of those examples, things are much vaguer with the first two.

Answer (score 1):

In English, the names of languages, regardless of where they appear, need to be capitalized.

E.g. I also speak French, in which capitalization of language names is incorrect.